# scull device driver in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am reading linux device driver book of rubini,corbet and hartmen.I did not understand these lines about scull device driver.This is what book says

**The only real operation performed on the device is truncating it to a length of 0 when
the device is opened for writing. This is performed because, by design, overwriting a
scull device with a shorter file results in a shorter device data area.**

Would be great help if someone explain how trimming is exactly done?What do you mean by overwriting a scull device with shorter file?

Answer (score 9):

The scull device in the book is simply an area of memory (RAM). So, when one overwrites it with a shorter file, it simply becomes a smaller area of memory (a.k.a shorter device data area). Therefore, when the device is opened for writing, the length should be truncated to 0 bytes (because we have not written anything yet. We have just opened it for writing).